# hubconnection start per every request and change context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I need to connect to my SignalR Core hub in my controller 
(I don't want to use dependency injection for invoking my hub methods)
but I don't want to start my `HubConnection` every time I call my controller
what should I do?

My controller:

```cs
private static readonly string url = "http://localhost:10580/sgr/rtc";
public HubConnection Connection { get; private set; } = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(url).Build();

public SampleDataController()
{
    Task.Run(async () => await Connection.StartAsync());
}

[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetConnectionId()
{
    try
    {
        var str = await Connection.InvokeAsync<string>("GetConnectionId");
        return Ok(str);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return BadRequest("Connection is not established");
    }
}
```

and my hub:

```cs
public string GetConnectionId()
{
    return Context.ConnectionId;
}
```

Now I get different `connectionId` for each request but I want to get just one `connectionId` for a client.

Comment: What is the reason you did not want to use `dependency injection ` and ` I don't want to start my HubConnection every time`? Do you mean you want to create and keep the connection all the time when the application start? In general, you could create the connection for every request.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to register `HubConnection` as `Singleton` like

```
public class Startup
{
    private static readonly string url = "https://localhost:44379/ChatHub";
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<HubConnection>((serviceProvider) => {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(url).Build();
            hubConnection.StartAsync().Wait();                
            return hubConnection;
        });           
    }

}
```

And then access `HubConnection` with

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly HubConnection Connection;
    public HomeController(HubConnection connection)
    {
        Connection = connection;
    }

}
```